# Adding the values into same row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables like this with the name in Table 2 as empty for ID=1. Now if I want to insert Table1 to Table 2 I don't a new row for ID=1.

```
Table1
----------
ID   Name
1    A
2    B
3    C

Table2
----------
ID   Name
1
```

Required Output:

```
ID   Name
1    A
2    B
3    C
```

Comment: I am new to this. trying myself for the solution. My project deadline is close. So I need help.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please check the FAQ [ask] on how to ask good questions, so that you get good answers. You should at least have tried something yourself and ideally show some **code** of what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a simple `merge`:

```
SQL> merge into t2
  2    using t1
  3    on (t1.id = t2.id)
  4    when matched then update set t2.name = t1.name
  5    when not matched then insert (id, name)
  6      values (t1.id, t1.name);

4 rows merged.

SQL> select * From t2 order by id;

        ID N
---------- -
         1 a
         2 b
         3 c
         4 d

SQL>
```

Comment: If there is more than one column which needs to be checked should I use 2 if conditions?

Comment: If you mean line #3 `on (t1.id = t2.id)` then yes; I used what you showed us.

Comment: Insert into t2(id,n) values (1,'A') , (2,'B'),(3,'C'). How can I do in this case without creating a duplicate row in t2?

Comment: INSERT you posted is invalid so I have no idea what you mean.